# Multiple apps sharing the same code: how to avoid this violation of the 12-factor app manifesto

Tags: git, heroku, github, 12factor

I have two java applications that both depend upon a library (i.e. my domain model).

I deploy to a PaaS - namely Heroku - that promotes the 12-factor architecture.

I use Git/Github as an SCM.

I am not sure how to organise my modules' source code with Git so that both applications can share the dependency/library and still respect the 12-factor manifesto.

I was thinking of importing the library's source code with `git pull -s subtree` and therefore have the library's source code within the two apps's source code.

Now: does that respect the 12-factor app manifesto? See: http://12factor.net/codebase.

> Multiple apps sharing the same code is a violation of twelve-factor.
>   The solution here is to factor shared code into libraries which can be
>   included through the dependency manager.

It seems a clear violation of the 12-factor app manifesto...

Now Heroku does not offer dependency manager feature.

So can someone please advise and provide a best practice?

Comment: It's describing git's submodules perfectly.  Stay aware that a submodule is nothing more than a nested repo, that your main repo commits nothing more than the id of a commit that's supposed to be somewhere in whatever repo you put at that path, and everything else is just handy-dandies, and you'll be fine.,

Comment: Thanks for suggesting git's submodules. Can you please explain how this solution is respecting the 12 factor app manifesto?

Comment: It says one codebase = one root commit, other code, code from another root, is either another app in a distributed system or a library/bundle/whatever dependency -- depending on unspecified criteria, though in most cases it looks easy to judge which.  Whichever, code from a separate root isn't part of the apps that depend on it, it's used by them.  That set looks like a pretty good set of rules for a starter kit, it's roughly how most good code and projects I've seen are structured.

Comment: Hi again. I have investigated the submodule solution and it seems Heroku does not support it as of now. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30534811/536299. Do you have alternatives/workarounds to suggest?

Comment: "GitHub does not include submodule contents when repo-content tarballs are generated."  Nothing says the current commit on any branch in any repo was the source of any commit id in another (whether or not it's in another repo) commit.  Build your deployment tree locally and combine the correct archives.

Comment: The issue described here is not related to a possible violation of the 12 factor. The issue is rather that Heroku can't deploy from a github submodules.

Comment: I was suggesting that if you can't get what you want from github, just build it yourself, it's not hard.