# Deploying a git branch together with its submodule from Github to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github, git-submodules

I am in reference to **Heroku's deployment from Github** feature that allows you to deploy from a Github branch to Heroku. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

I would like to know if I can deploy from a github project that includes a git submodule?

If so what are the necessary steps other that running the submodule command below on my project?

```
git submodule add git://github.com/whomsoever/whatever.git
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have found the answer to my question and unfortunately it does not seem possible to achieve what I want i.e. to deploy a github repo that uses submodules...

To quote the official Heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#git-submodules):

> GitHub repos that use submodules will generally not deploy correctly
>   on Heroku. This is because GitHub does not include submodule contents
>   when repo-content tarballs are generated.

Comment: It looks like there is a way to do now. If you are deploying with Git push https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules